# Android - try to get right to left notification message order in FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

lately I've implemented Firebase cloud messaging in my project, and everything works just fine!

Except the title and body message is in left to right order, is there  any hacks that I can change it to right to left?

What do you guys suggest?

EDIT:
the current notification looks like this

[image]

but I want the title and message body to be right to left,

and rtl attribute in manifest is `android:supportsRtl="false".

and this is the current Json I send to the fire-base server

```
   {
  "collapse_key" : "demo",
  "to" :"xyz",
  "notification" : {
  "body_loc_key" : "welcome_messages",
  "body_loc_args":["غلام" , "1500"],
  "title" : "عنوان متن"
},
 "data" : {
 "key1" : "value1",
 "key2" : "value2"
  },
 "time_to_live" : 3
 }
```

Comment: Post current and expected result. What is the source of the message? what is the recipient of the message? Do any of these run in RTL environments? Please answer all questions.

Comment: Why is `android:supportsRtl="false"` if you need to support RTL? Is the system language RTL?

Comment: It's beacause it wrecks  everything, this is not the point, I mean if I make it true, it doesn't change anything on the notification

Comment: That's why I asked. (Offtopic: You need to adjust [`android:textDirection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection) to make it work.) If you change the system language to an RTL one, does it work as intended?

Comment: @eugen-pechanec you right, it changes when I change the system language to rtl one, but I want to change it prgogrammatically